# Debug Filter option which only list System.debug statements?

Tags: apex, debug

Is there a way to filter option where ONLY `system.debug` statements are listed and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to debug logs and click on 'filter' beside your user under monitored users.

apex debug codes are usually placed under the 'debug' level so set the other levels to 'none' and adjust accordingly :)

Comment: And for this reason, I usually use System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR ...) so that I can turn the logs down as far as possible to reduce the extra stuff that appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the developer console, run whatever transaction you are debugging, open the appropriate log, and select the Debug Only checkbox in the bottom left.

[image]